# Why is 'name' nil for debug.getinfo(1)

Tags: lua, lua-5.1

I'm trying to put together a lua testing framework that lets you know the function that had the problem, but when I switched from loadstring to `_G`, (I switched so my test harness could see the results of the function call) my functions started using 'nil' for the function name

Why can `_G` not detect the name of the current function in the following code?  Also, how can I get the return results from loadstring (ie the 'false' from the blah call) or set the function name when using `_G` (ie. Tell the lua interpreter what the function name should be)?

```
function run_test(one, two)
    if one ~= two then
        print(debug.getinfo(2).name..' Failed')
    end
end

function blah()
    run_test(false, true)
    return false
end

local fname = 'blah'
local status, result = pcall(_G[fname])  -- Outputs 'nil'; result is 'false'
local status, result = pcall(loadstring(fname..'()'))  -- Outputs 'blah', result is 'nil'
```

The main thing I need is a way to call a function using a string of the function name, be able to see the function name inside the call (for test failures to point to the function that failed, like fname = 'blah' in the code above) and be able to get the return value

```
local fname = 'blah'
status, result = pcall(??Call fname somehow??)
assert(status)
assert(not result)

--stdout should be "blah Failed"
```

Comment: Just a guess here but could it be because `pcall` goes into C land and function values on the stack doesn't have an associated symbolic name in this context?

Comment: Both lines are using pcall. Plus, it's opposite of what I'd expect since loadstring is 'more' dynamic than _G

Comment: yes but the second line has the effect of wrapping an anonymous function over `blah` and this goes back to lua land.

Answer (score 3):

This is a limitation of the heuristics used by Lua to provide names for functions.

In Lua, all functions are anonymous. A given function can be the value of several variables: global, local, and table fields. The Lua debug system tries to find a reasonable name for a value based on where it came from by looking into the bytecode being executed.

Consider the simpler example

```
blah()
pcall(blah)
```

In the first call, the debug system sees that the function being called comes from the global `blah` and `debug.getinfo(1).name` gives the expected result, `blah`.

In the second call, the debug system sees that the function being called comes from the first argument to `pcall` but it does not look further to see where that argument came from, and `debug.getinfo(1).name` gives `nil`.

The same thing happens when you call `_G[name]()`. All the debug system sees is a field of a table and the name of the field is too far off.

Try adding `print(debug.traceback())` as the first line of `blah` to see another take on this explanation.

Comment: Any ideas on my second question?

Comment: @solarmist Are you referring to the question of getting return results back? Do you mean like getting back whatever `blah` returns?

Comment: Yes, getting back what 'blah' returns or faking a name for the _G call.

Comment: @solarmist wouldn't something like `pcall(loadstring('return '..name..'()'))` do the trick?

Comment: @solarmist hmm for some strange reason, `debug.getinfo` is also unable to get name from `return blah()`. But this seems to work `pcall( loadstring('return unpack{'..name..'()}') )`.

Comment: Try passing in a name to the second argument of `loadstring`. http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-loadstring